# Adding a substring to each line in a string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have a string in a variable in MATLAB like the following:

```
this is the first line 
this is the second line 
this is the third line
```

I would like to add a fixed string **at the beginning** of each line. For example:

```
add_substring(input_string, 'add_this. ')
```

would output:

```
add_this. this is the first line 
add_this. this is the second line 
add_this. this is the third line
```

I know I can do this by looping through the input string, but I am looking for a more compact (hopefully vectorized) way to do this, perhaps using one of MATLAB built-ins such as `arrayfun` `accumarray`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `strcat` function is what you're looking for. It does vectorized concatenation of strings.

```
strs = {
    'this is the first line'
    'this is the second line'
    'this is the third line'
    }
strcat({'add_this. '}, strs)
```

With strcat, you need to put `'add_this. '` in a cell (`{}`) to protect it from having its trailing whitespace stripped, which is strcat's normal behavior for char inputs.

Comment: The input string was technically not a cell array but a char string, but I can convert it to one using `[input_string, ~]   = regexp(input_string , '\n', 'split');`

Comment: `Strcat` works on `char` input, too. But you'd still need to do that split, because multiple strings as `char` are stored as separate rows in a 2-d char matrix; looks like your input was a single multi-line string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings are stored in a cell array then `cellfun` will do what you want, e.g.

```
s = {'this is the first line', 'this is the second line', 'this is the third line'};
prefix = 'add_this. ';
res = cellfun(@(str) strcat(prefix, str), s, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Check the `res` output; prefix is being stripped.