# Add "x,y,z," to first line of .txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am working with Matlab code that writes coordinates to a text file as follows:

```
838959.41800,4713239.59000,1.00000,841305.41800,4708452.59000,1.00000,839175.41800,4712582.59000,1.00000
```

In the past, I've had to open each file individually and add the following to the first line of the .txt document:

```
x,y,z,
838959.41800,4713239.59000,1.00000,841305.41800,4708452.59000,1.00000,839175.41800,4712582.59000,1.00000
```

Any ideas on how to automate this process by embedding code which will write "`x,y,z,`" to the first line of the Matlab output?

Thanks much,

-Aaron

Comment: How writes your code your coordinates to file? Because Matlab offers output formats to append text. Don't have key words here. But maybe it is faster to put your line in front of string which you save. Here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912648/adding-a-substring-to-each-line-in-a-string-in-matlab?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: How do you insert a line of text at the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638960/matlab-how-do-you-insert-a-line-of-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: @Amro: I don't really think it's a duplicate, in that question the data wasn't generated in MatLab, so you didn't have the option to simply add a header row before writing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I guess you're right.. Well then ignore my close-vote (let it expire), and simply consider it a similar question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
x = rand(1,3);
y = rand(1,3);
z = rand(1,3);

fid = fopen('data.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, 'x,y,z,\n');
fprintf([repmat('%.6f,',[1 8]) '%.6f\n'], x,y,z)
fclose(fid);
```

The output file:

#### data.txt

```
x,y,z,
0.694829,0.317099,0.950222,0.034446,0.438744,0.381558,0.765517,0.795200,0.186873
```